# Prove the existence of a smooth global frames on $\mathbb{S}^7$.

Tags: smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

I was in trouble when I was trying to complete problem 8-7 in Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds in Chapter 8. The problem is

> The algebra of octonions(also called Cayley numbers) is the $8-$dimensional real vector space $\mathbb{O}=\mathbb{H}\times\mathbb{H}$ with
> the following bilinear product:
> $$ (p,q)(r,s)=(pr-sq^*,p^*+rq),\quad p,q,r,s\in \mathbb{H} $$
> Show that $\mathbb{O}$ is a noncommutative, nonassociative algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, and prove that there exists a
> smooth global frame on $\mathbb{S}^7$ by imitating as much of Problem 8-6 as you can.

Here is my idea. Note that $\mathbb{H}=\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}$, and $\mathbb{O}=\mathbb{H}\times\mathbb{H}$. Then we can think of $\mathbb{O}$ as a product manifold of $\mathbb{R}\times 8$. Then for any $Q\in \mathbb{O}$, we have the coordinate of $Q=(x^1,\cdots,x^8)$ where $x^i\in \mathbb{R}$.

Consider the next function
$$ A:\mathbb{O}^*\to \mathbb{R} $$
s.t. for all $Q=(p,q)\in \mathbb{O}^*=\{(x^1,\cdots,x^8)\in\mathbb{O}:(x^1)^2+\cdots+(x^8)^2\ne 0\}$, $A(Q)=(x^1)^2+\cdots+(x^8)^2$. It's clear that $A$ is smooth and
$$dA_Q=2(x^1,\cdots,x^8)$$
then $rank(dA_Q)=1$ i.e. $A$ is submersion. Note that $\mathbb{S}^7=A^{-1}(1)$ which mean that $\mathbb{S}^7$ is embedded submersion of $\mathbb{O}^*$ and $A$ is defining map of $\mathbb{S}^7$. Then
$$T_Q\mathbb{S}^7=\ker dA_Q=\{P\in \mathbb{O}:Q\cdot P=0\}$$
where the $\cdot$ mean the dot product operator in $\mathbb{R}^8$. Let
$$1=(1,0),\quad I=(i,0),\quad J=(j,0),\quad K=(k,0),\quad L=(0,1),\quad M=(0,i),\quad N=(0,j),\quad O=(0,k)$$
where $1, i,j,k\in \mathbb{H}$. Consider the next vector fields
$$ X_1|_Q=QI,\quad X_2|_Q=QJ,\quad X_3|_Q=QK,\quad X_4|_Q=QL $$
$$ X_5|_Q=QM,\quad X_6|_Q=QN,\quad X_7|_Q=QO $$
The above vector fields are linearly independent since octonionic multiplication satisfies the distribute law. To modify the proof of problem 8-6, we need to prove that $X_1,\cdots, X_7$ tangent to $\mathbb{S}^7$.

For $X_1|_Q$, it's easy to compute that
$$X_1|_Q=(-x^2,x^1,-x^4,x^3,-x^6,x^5,-x^8,x^7)$$
then $Q\cdot X_1|_Q=0$ i.e. $X_1|_Q\in T_Q\mathbb{S}^7$. So $X_1$ tangent to $\mathbb{S}^7$. But for $X_2|_Q$, we compute next
$$X_2|_Q=(-x^3,x^4,x^1,-x^2,x^7,x^8,x^5,x^6)$$
and
$$Q\cdot X_2|_Q=x^5x^7+x^6x^8+x^7x^5+x^8x^6$$
we can not confirm $Q\cdot X_2|_Q$ is vanish.

Where is the wrong in my computation? Could anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: @JesseMadnick Maybe it's typed wrong and I have edited it.

Comment: Hint: the tangent space $T_pS^7$ is $\{p\}^{\perp}$

Comment: @Didier I have proved $T_Q\mathbb{S}^7=\{Q\}^{\bot}$, what I confused is $X_2$ cann't tangent to $\mathbb{S}^7$.

Comment: Then you have made an error in your computations somewhere. It is easy to see that $J$ satisfies $J^2 = -Id$ and $\langle XJ,YJ \rangle = \langle X,Y\rangle$ for any $X,Y$, and therefore, $\langle X,XJ \rangle = \langle XJ,XJ^2 \rangle = -\langle XJ,X\rangle = -\langle X,XJ\rangle$, from which follows that $\langle X,XJ\rangle = 0$, that is $XJ\perp X$ for all $X$.

Comment: There is an error in the definition of the multiplication in your question. Indeed, $(1,0)\cdot(0,0) = (0,1)$ with your definition, which is not meant to be the case. It should be $(a,b)\cdot(c,d) = (ac -d^*b,da + bc^*)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $J_1,\ldots,J_7$ be the right multiplication by $(i,0), (j,0), (k,0), (0,1), (0,i), (0,j)$ and $(0,k)$ respectively.
Let $X=(p,q) \in \Bbb O$.
Then
$$
J_1X
= (p,q)\cdot(i,0)
= (ip, -qi),
$$
and therefore
$$
J_1^2 X
= \big((p,q)\cdot(i,0)\big)\cdot(i,0)
= (ip, -qi)\cdot(i,0)
= (i^2p,qi^2)
= -(p,q)
= -X.
$$
Similarly,
$$
J_2X
= (p,q)\cdot(j,0)
= (jp,-qj),
$$
and
$$
J_2^2X
= \big((p,q)\cdot(j,0)\big)\cdot(j,0)
= (jp,-qj)\cdot(j,0)
= (j^2p,qj^2)
= -(p,q)
= -X.
$$
The exact same computations show that $\forall \ell \in \{1,\ldots,7\}$, $J_{\ell}^2 = - \mathrm{Id}_{\Bbb O}$.

An important property of the octonion norm is that for any $X$ and $Y$, we have $\|X \cdot Y\| = \|X\|\|Y\|$, where $\|X\| = \sqrt{X^*X}$ is the usual euclidean norm of $\Bbb O \simeq \Bbb R^8$ in the canonical coordinates.
This implies that $\|J_{\ell} X\| = \|X\|$ for all $\ell \in\{1,\ldots,7\}$ and $X\in \Bbb O$.
By standard euclidean theory, for $\ell\in\{1,\ldots,7\}$, $J_{\ell}$ is a linear isometry of $\Bbb O$: for all $X$ and $Y$, one has
$$
\langle J_{\ell} X, J_{\ell}Y\rangle
= \langle X,Y \rangle.
$$
Applying this equality to $Y = J_{\ell} X$, we obtain that $J_{\ell}X \perp X$ for all $X$.
In fact, if $\ell_1 \neq \ell_2 \in \{1,\ldots,7\}$, one can show that $J_{\ell_1} J_{\ell_2} = \pm J_{\ell_3}$ for some $\ell_3 \in \{1,\ldots,7\}$, and thus, we have
$$
\langle J_{\ell_1}X,J_{\ell_2}X \rangle
= \langle X, -J_{\ell_1}J_{\ell_2}X\rangle
= \langle X, \mp J_{\ell_3}X \rangle
= 0,
$$
and $J_{\ell_1}X \perp J_{\ell_2}X$.
It follows that if $X \neq 0$, then $\{X,J_1X,\ldots,J_7X\}$ is an orthogonal basis of $\Bbb O$.
If moreover $\|X\|=1$, then it is an orthonormal basis.

Now, to go back to the original question, notice that if $X \in \Bbb S^7 =\{ Y \in \Bbb O \mid \|Y\|=1\}$, then $T_X\Bbb S^7 = \{X\}^{\perp}$.
Since $\{X,J_1X,\ldots,J_7X\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb O$, then $\{J_1X,\ldots,J_7X\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\{X\}^{\perp} = T_X\Bbb S^7$.
It follows that $T\Bbb S^7$ is trivial: a global trivialization is given by
$$
(X,Y) \in T\Bbb S^7 \mapsto \big(X, (\langle Y,J_1X \rangle,\ldots,\langle Y,J_7X\rangle) \big) \in \Bbb S^7 \times \Bbb R^7.
$$

Comment: Using the definition of Lee's, I modify the proof of you that I can also prove $X_1,\cdots, X_7$ tangent to $\mathbb{S}^7$. But why do I directedly compute $QJ$ that I can not confirm $QJ\cdot Q=0$?

Comment: @Lacen As I said in the comments above, there is an error in your definition of the octonionic multiplication. Maybe you also made errors while computing. It may be as simple as that